# How does Ninject and MVC resolve this custom attribute to the custom action filter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ninject, inversion-of-control, action-filter, actionfilterattribute

I actually have the following code working, but I really am not sure how MVC or Ninject is actually able to bind the LogFilter to the ILoggerMVCAttribute.  I guess at some level it makes sense that a filter would have attributes, but I just am not seeing what commonality (interface or base class) allows this to happen. Just trying to gain a better understanding, in case I need to do something like this again in the future.  Thanks in advance.

```
//Basic trimmed down code
//Custom Action Filter
public class LogFilter : System.Web.Mvc.IActionFilter
{
    public class ILogger logger {get;set;}

    public LogFilter(ILogger logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        LogRequest(logger);
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {

    }

}
//Custom Action Filter Attribute
public class ILoggerMVCAttribute : FilterAttribute { }

//Ninject binding the action filter to the action filter attribute.
this.BindFilter<LogFilter>(System.Web.Mvc.FilterScope.Controller, 0)
            .WhenControllerHas<ILoggerMVCAttribute>();
```

For the record, I did not end up using the above approach for my logging. I was able to get the current instance of my logger in the Global.asax LogRequest as follows.

```
protected void Application_LogRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ILogger log = this.Kernel.Get<ILogger>();        
    LogRequest(log);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Ninject.MVC extension has its own MVC FilterProvider:

https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/blob/master/mvc3/src/Ninject.Web.Mvc/Filter/NinjectFilterProvider.cs

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  It helps with understanding why the code works.